# Confusion over organization of services

Tags: object-oriented, mvc, application-design

I have the following services:

**UserServices** This has various methods: fetch_by_id(), create() etc.

**SessionServices** Session handling: create(), destroy(), various getters.

**AnswerServices** An answer is an entity, it represents an answer to a question. These are the services related to it.

Now the problem is I'd like to add a method to get all answers a user has given.

Do I put this into the **UserServices** or the **AnswerServices**? I have a number of methods similar to this for other entities, but I'm struggling to figure out where those methods belong.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I would say it really doesn't matter. My tendency would be to put it on Answer. Note: You are looking at services as though they are normalized data tables. That may be alright if your use cases are all crud operations but you may want to consider another service that deals with non-CRUD use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have not tagged this with REST, I think if you look up services in REST you can find quite a bit of consensus on how to handle this.

First of all, you are looking for answers, not users. The fact that you are filtering based on user is secondary to the fact that *you need answers*.

This method belongs on AnswerServices, with a filter by user.

```
AnswerServices.getForUser(UserId id);
```